# How can I tell the difference between "an hour" meaning "per hour" versus "in one hour's time"?

Tags: word-usage

The "an" can be used as a preposition with the meaning of "per": *My rate is $10 an hour*.

Also it can be a used as a determiner: *I will be ready in an hour*.

How can I tell these 2 apart?

Comment: "An" is used as a determiner in both cases. In the first example "a(n) X" it is used following a quantity without a preposition, in the second it is used with a preposition.

Comment: Are you saying that "per" is missing but implied?

Comment: No. Nothing is "missing". I'm saying that "per" is not required: that's what the construction means. "Per" is a different way of saying the same thing. You can also say "each hour", "every hour".

Comment: It's not really "missing", but you can easily assume the elided preposition *"My rate is $10 **for** an/one/each hour."*

Answer (score 3):

It's the same for any word that has multiple meanings; you have to determine it from context. As you said, *an* can mean something similar to *per*, or it can be used to mean *a/one*. If you take your two examples and substitute the 'definitions' instead of the word *an* in each case, it is quickly clear which makes sense and which doesn't:

> My rate is $10 per hour.

Meaning: "I charge $10 for each hour" - makes sense

> My rate is $10 one hour.

Meaning: Nothing; this doesn't make sense as an English sentence. So you know this isn't the correct meaning.

> I will be ready in one hour.

Meaning: "When one hour has passed, I will be ready" - makes sense

> I will be ready in per hour.

Meaning: Again, nothing; this just doesn't make sense.

So as you can see, if you know multiple meanings of a word, you can substitute each meaning into the sentence and see if the sentence makes sense. That way you can tell from the context which definition applies.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute *per* for *a(n)*.  If it's ungrammatical, it can't mean *per*.

> My rate is $10 **an** hour.
>   My rate is $10 **per** hour.

This example works.

> I will be ready in **an** hour.
>   ＊I will be ready in **per** hour.

This example does not.  In this sentence, the preposition *in* needs to be followed by a noun phrase; *an hour* works as a noun phrase, but *per hour* is a preposition phrase, so it's ungrammatical.

In other words, you can distinguish the two syntactically.

Comment: Oops, I see that this is more or less what WendiKidd's answer says.  I'll go upvote that answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely by context.  In the first case you have a unit $10 and a measurement the "hour".  In the second you're specifying a time allotment.

Comment: Well, how is the context different? Can you name formal differences?

Comment: Formal references?

Example 1: I'm driving at 50 miles an hour.

Example 2: I'm going to leave here in an hour.

Comment: differences not examples

Comment: @bonomo As WendiKidd points out, there is no preposition in [measure1] a(n) [measure2]: [$10] an [hour], [35 miles] a [gallon]. The default parsing of the idiom is that [measure1] is divided by one [measure2].

Comment: @StoneyB, any other cases you can think of? I need to teach a program how to tell these two apart so I need as many clues as possible.

Comment: @bonomo Any other cases of the constructions? *It prints  [15 pages] a [minute] .. I get [3 weeks] a [year] vacation .. This cake has [800 calories] a [serving] .. ELL currently gets [1,048 visits] a [day]* ... but I thought you wanted "formal differences" not "cases"?

Comment: @StoneyB, thank you for examples, although they all revolve around the same pattern. The formal differences are what I am actually looking for, I hesitate to pose a question like that because not everybody has a formal mindset, so to get some cases would be good too as I can deduce the patterns out of them.

Comment: @StoneyB, never mind, I think I've got it. Thank you!

Comment: @bonomo Many here have very formal mindsets. SE, after all, is populated mostly by programmers. The spec you're looking for is *Quantity AUnits **a** BUnit*.

Comment: @StoneyB: As suggested by the date of [*...are offering a limited number of sets of this series of ten volumes for five pounds **the** set*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22ten+volumes+for+five+pounds+the+set%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), the definite article is at least somewhat "dated". But it certainly occurs even today, quite naturally in some contexts.

Comment: ...personally, I don't have a problem with *"The hire charge is £10 **a** day, or £40 **the** week"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Quite so; but OP's question concerned the indefinite article.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, OP's question certainly doesn't concern the average English language learner. It looks to me like a (probably doomed) attempt to write a computer-based natural language parser that recognises the *"QuantityA **per** QuantityB"* relationship. But I'd have thought the nature of that relationship (and hence the possible alternatives to ***per***) vary considerably according to the preceding ***verb***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can you think of a context in which **n NOUNs a/the/each/every NOUN** is *not* equivalent to a *per* relationship?

Comment: @StoneyB: Not offhand, no (I'm quite prepared to believe there are none). But what I meant was the *exact* nature of the relationship can vary considerably, and not all variants of the "relationship operator" ([for] a/the/each/every/etc.) work in all contexts. Somewhere in the general area you'd need to deal with things like *"It's every man for himself"*, where "per" doesn't really seem very relevant.

Comment: @Stoney: consider *"I need ten dollars an hour from now"* versus *"I need ten dollars an hour from now on".*

Comment: @PeterShor Oh, very nice. And could be genuinely ambiguous in writing: "I will be getting $4,000 a month from next week".

Comment: @StoneyB: Wonderful example!